# Force showing keyboard in metro?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'd like to be able to force the keyboard to show on screen in my Metro app. My goal is to test out different layouts/controls and get a feel for the interaction. My problem is that I'm running Win8 on a MacBook Pro (Parallels) and I don't know how to override the physical keyboard and show it on screen instead.

Similarly, I'd like to be able to force rotation if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could run your app the [Simulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441475%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You can put the Simulator in "Touch Mode" and that will interpret mouse clicks as touch events in the on screen controls like Text Boxes and you can choose to rotate the Simulator into profile as well.