# WinForms in Windows RT

Tags: winforms, windows-rt

I have a WinForms application written in .NET Framework 2.0. Can it run on a Windows RT device ?

If not which tablet would run my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the System.Windows.Forms is not supported in Windows Store Application.

You can see all .NET assembly available on Windows Store App on this link :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232.aspx

Your application may not run on the Windows RT tablet, but tablets running full Windows 8 will be fine (Microsoft Surface Pro).

[Do simple Windows Forms/WPF apps work on Windows 8 for tablets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548792/does-simple-windows-forms-work-on-windows-8-and-windows-8-tablets)